# Lucene - simpleAnalyzer - How to get matched word(s)?

Tags: search, lucene, full-text-search, analyzer

I can't get offset of or directly the word itself by using the following algorithm. Any help would be appreciated

```
   ...
   Analyzer analyzer = new SimpleAnalyzer();
   MemoryIndex index = new MemoryIndex();

   QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "content", analyzer);

   float score = index.search(parser.parse("+content:" + target));

   if(score > 0.0f)
        System.out.println("How to know matched word?");
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is whole in memory index and search example. I have just written in for my self and it works perfectly. I understand that you need to store index in memory, but the question is why you need `MemoryIndex` for that? You simply use `RAMDirectory` instead and your index will be stored in memory, so when you perform your search, index will be loaded from RAMDirectory (memory).

```
    StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_34);
    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_34, analyzer);
    RAMDirectory directory = new RAMDirectory();
    try {
        IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.add(new Field("content", text, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.WITH_OFFSETS));
        indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
        indexWriter.optimize();
        indexWriter.close();

        QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_34, "content", analyzer);
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory, true);
        IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(directory, true);

        Query query = parser.parse(word);
        TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(10000, true);
        searcher.search(query, collector);
        ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
        if (hits != null && hits.length > 0) {
            for (ScoreDoc hit : hits) {
                int docId = hit.doc;
                Document hitDoc = searcher.doc(docId);

                TermFreqVector termFreqVector = reader.getTermFreqVector(docId, "content");
                TermPositionVector termPositionVector = (TermPositionVector) termFreqVector;
                int termIndex = termFreqVector.indexOf(word);
                TermVectorOffsetInfo[] termVectorOffsetInfos = termPositionVector.getOffsets(termIndex);

                for (TermVectorOffsetInfo termVectorOffsetInfo : termVectorOffsetInfos) {
                    concordances.add(processor.processConcordance(hitDoc.get("content"), word, termVectorOffsetInfo.getStartOffset(), size));
                }
            }
        }

        analyzer.close();
        searcher.close();
        directory.close();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Can you convert your sample to memoryIndex usage? That's why I use memoryIndex for full text search, I cannot use hits or doc like those in your code.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I use memoryIndex because of performance and memory issues I have learnt that MemoryIndex is more efficient and convenient rather than RAMDirectory, and that's why I prefer to choose MemoryIndex.

Comment: Then my suggestion will be to get Lucene in Action book. It will save you a lot of time and issues of using Lucene.

Comment: This class is a replacement/substitute for a large subset of RAMDirectory functionality. It is designed to enable maximum efficiency for on-the-fly matchmaking combining structured and fuzzy fulltext search in realtime streaming applications such as Nux XQuery based XML message queues, publish-subscribe systems for Blogs/newsfeeds, text chat, data acquisition and distribution systems, application level routers, firewalls, classifiers, etc... http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_4_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/memory/MemoryIndex.html

Comment: The close statements should be in a finally block, each preceded by a not null test.

Comment: Please notice that they are all created with `new` so they aren't ever gonna be null.

Comment: You can use the MemoryIndex with a searcher. MemoryIndex provides a createSearcher() method. And then you have all the TopDocs functionality you need.

Comment: @nbz could you provide an example of searching a MemoryIndex for docs ?